# Can only access WCF Workflow Service Endpoint Remotely

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, workflow-foundation

I am hosting a Workflow Service on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I am accessing it via a windows service / topshelf enabled console application running on the same server. The issue is, I cannot access the endpoint locally (from the same server) but can access it from any other server (using exact same service accounts, same domain).

My client (windows service) bindings look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BindingIBeginNewRequestAdded">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://WorkFlowServerTest.corp.gdg/NewAccountRequestWorkflow.xamlx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BindingIBeginNewRequestAdded" contract="NewAccountRequest.IBeginNewRequestAdded" name="BindingIBeginNewRequestAdded"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

WorkFlow Service bindings look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HTTPSBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MEXHTTPSBindingConfiguration">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="HTTPSBehavior" name="NewAccountRequestWorkflow">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MEXHTTPSBindingConfiguration" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HTTPSBindingConfiguration" name="SecureTransportNoCredentialsEndpoint6" contract="IBeginNewRequestAdded" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

C#/Windows Service Code:

```
NewAccountRequest.BeginNewRequestAddedClient _ws = new NewAccountRequest.BeginNewRequestAddedClient();
_ws.BeginNewRequestAdded(_newRequest.RequestID);
```

Error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at WinSvc.DailySales.NewAccountRequest.IBeginNewRequestAdded.BeginNewRequestAdded(BeginNewRequestAddedRequest request)
   at WinSvc.DailySales.NewAccountRequest.BeginNewRequestAddedClient.WinSvc.DailySales.NewAccountRequest.IBeginNewRequestAdded.BeginNewRequestAdded(BeginNewRequestAddedRequest request)
   at WinSvc.DailySales.Classes.DailySalesExceptionHandler.CallGPAccountSubmitService()
```

So I'm aware of this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861

And have already added BackConnectionHostNames of: WorkFlowServerTest.corp.gdg to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0.

I have tried every combination of client and server clientCredentialType and Security Mode settings in the bindings. Lost...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the registry setting: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\BackConnectionHostNames

... was incorrect!

So, I tried pointing this to my WorkFlowServerTest.corp.gdg DNS. But that DNS is nothing more than a CName which is pointed to one of the FQDNs of that server. Resolution:

Ping that CNAME/DNS name to get the IP Address. NSLOOKUP that IP to get the FQDN. Set the registry key to the FQDN and fix it. Fixed!